# React Native: vertical text align works on Android but not iOS

Tags: android, react-native

I have this component:

```
<View style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <Icon
    name={iconName}
    type="font-awesome-5"
    style={{ paddingRight: 10, minWidth: 30, backgroundColor: 'red' }}
    color={theme?.colors?.white}
  />
  <Text
    style={{
      fontSize: 20,
      color: theme?.colors?.white,
      paddingVertical: 5,
      backgroundColor: 'green',
    }}
  >
    {label}
  </Text>
</View>
```

On Android, the elements are aligned as one would expect. On iOS, the alignment is too far to the top:

Android:
[image: Android]

iOS:
[image: iOS]

Additional info: this component is nested within the application, and I haven't provided all that since it is a larger app, but I could provide snippets if that would be helpful. I'm still new to React Native so I'm not sure how deep the styling rabbit hole goes.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to admit defeat and work around the problem. At least it is confined to one component, so I did a little style sheet like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    icon: {
      paddingRight: 10,
      minWidth: 30,
      marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 6 : 0,
    },
    text: {
      fontSize: 20,
      color: theme?.colors?.white,
      marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 6 : 0,
    },
  });
```

and used that in the code like this:

```
<View style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <Icon
    name={iconName}
    type="font-awesome-5"
    style={styles.icon}
    color={theme?.colors?.white}
  />
  <Text
    style={styles.text}
  >
    {label}
  </Text>
</View>
```

Not ideal, but it got the job done.